# diff: Only compare files and ignore subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, diff

I'm trying to compare two directories, each with some files and a subdirectory. Is there any way to run diff on these two folders, but not run it on the subdirectory? I've tried using `diff -x'*/' foo bar`, as well as a couple variants with backslashes to escape them, but no dice.

The actual name of the subdirectory can change, which is why I don't want to specify an exact name pattern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already diffing two specific directories, then I assume you know their names. In this case all you need to determine dynamically is the list of sub-directories contained in each.

Assuming you are in a parent directory; you have a structure like so, and you want to diff `foo` and `bar` but you want to exclude `baz` and `quux`:

```
+-- foo/
|     |-- baz/
|     |
|     +-- file.txt
|
+-- bar/
      |-- quux/
      |
      +-- file.txt
```

Using `find`:

```
find * -mindepth 1 -type d
```

Yields a list of subdirs inside `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo/baz
bar/quux
```

At this point you could write this to a temporary file:

```
find * -mindepth 1 -type d > exclude.txt
```

And then use `diff`'s `-X` flag, which allows you to specifies a file containing patterns to exclude from a diff.

This won't quite work however, because you'll need to slice the parent dir name off each result. We can use `cut` to do this:

```
find * -mindepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f2 > exclude.txt
```

This yields the following:

```
baz
quux
```

So you can now use:

```
diff -X exclude.txt foo bar
```

Or, if you don't want to create a temporary file you can do it as a one-liner:

```
diff -uX <(find * -mindepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f2) foo bar
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: oops, I see the question was accepted whilst I was writing!

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed, thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem! Really interesting question. Again, apologies for answering the question when it had already been accepted - I was busy reading man pages :)

Answer (score 2):

If you simply do `diff` on the directory names, without adding a `-r` option, GNU diff will report different subdirectory *names* but not recur into diff'ing their contents.

This is documented in detail in the GNU diff manual: *[4 Comparing Directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Comparing-Directories.html)*.

If you want to filter out the directory names, you *could* pipe the diff through a script which looks for lines beginning with "Only" and ignores those where the part after ":" is a directory name.  `diff`'s output format is reasonably predictable. One thing that makes it easy to parse is that the *content* (differences) is indented by one space, allowing the use of the first column for *markup*.

Here is a simple Perl script which relies upon a side effect of GNU diff's `-N` option to simplify the filtering (tested with version 3.0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

die "usage: $0 sourcedir targetdir"
  unless ( $#ARGV == 1 and -d $ARGV[0] and -d $ARGV[1] );

open FP, "diff -u -N \"" . $ARGV[0] . "\" \"" . $ARGV[1] . "\" |"
  or die "diff: $!";
while (<FP>) {
    print unless ( $_ =~ /^Com/ );
}
close FP;

1;
```

The `-N` option tells `diff` to pretend that each side of the comparison exists, so that it says "Common subdirectories" for *every* subdirectory.

Comment: Is there a way to have it not report it at all? I'm using the output of the diff in another step of a script, which causes the final output to be a bit mangled if they get compared.